# Mongodb aggregation with filter embedded document NoseJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm consulting my API and I pass as parameters an array of stations

> http: // localhost: 3790 / api / getSensorIdstation / 191,1123

The answer I get is the following:

```
   {
   "Station_types":[
      {
         "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":[
            "191",
            "457",
            "459",
            "463",
            "465",
            "426",
            "424"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"2",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/temp.png",
            "name_comun":"Temp. Ambiente",
            "medida":"ºC",
            "interfaz":"greenhouse"
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":[
            "191",
            "457",
            "459",
            "463",
            "465",
            "426",
            "424"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"3",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
            "medida":"%",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cebaa26c6b02a54c6a3f782",
         "marca":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "modelo":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "fabricante":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "id_station":[
            "1123"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"3",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
            "medida":"%",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cebaa26c6b02a54c6a3f782",
         "marca":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "modelo":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "fabricante":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "id_station":[
            "1123"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"43",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/humidity.png",
            "name_comun":"Def. vapor de presión",
            "medida":"kPa",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would need only the ID that is being consulted in this case on id_station appear in 191 and 1123, not the rest.

I am testing with the filters but it does not work correctly.

This is my code:

```
   function getSensorIdstation(req, res) {
        var array = req.params.id_station;
        var arr = array.split(',');
        Station_types.aggregate([
                { "$match": { "id_station": { "$in": arr } } },
                { "$unwind": "$sensor_type" },


            ],
            (err, Station_types) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' })
                if (!Station_types) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })

                res.status(200).send({ Station_types })
            })
    }
```

the result should be this:

```
{
   "Station_types":[
      {
         "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":[
            "191"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"2",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/temp.png",
            "name_comun":"Temp. Ambiente",
            "medida":"ºC",
            "interfaz":"greenhouse"
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":[
            "191"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"3",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
            "medida":"%",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cebaa26c6b02a54c6a3f782",
         "marca":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "modelo":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "fabricante":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "id_station":[
            "1123"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"3",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
            "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
            "medida":"%",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"5cebaa26c6b02a54c6a3f782",
         "marca":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "modelo":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "fabricante":"Sigfox 8DF004 CO2 Sensirion (L1 214)",
         "id_station":[
            "1123"
         ],
         "sensor_type":{
            "name":"43",
            "type":"clima",
            "place":"interior",
            "img":"assets/img/humidity.png",
            "name_comun":"Def. vapor de presión",
            "medida":"kPa",
            "interfaz":""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

> EDIT

add filter code:
but it does not return the rest of fields, only the id_station

```
Station_types.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "id_station": { "$in": arr } } },

            { "$unwind": "$sensor_type" },
            {
                $project: {
                    sensor_type: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$id_station',
                            as: 'shape',
                            cond: { $in: ['$$shape', arr] }
                        }
                    },
                    _id: 0
                }
            }

        ],
```

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem right now, I'm sorry, but I'd like to suggest that you don't name your aggregation result "Station_types", like your mongoose scheme, because you're overwriting it (only in the scope of this function, but I think it's not good practice)

Comment: Now it only shows the ID_station and not the rest of the information.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution after several tests, added a filter within the project and added the rest of the fields.

```
 function getSensorIdstation(req, res) {
        var array = req.params.id_station;
        console.log(array);

        var arr = array.split(',');
        console.log(arr);

        Station_types.aggregate([
                { "$match": { "id_station": { "$in": arr } } },

                { "$unwind": "$sensor_type" },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        id_station: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: '$id_station',
                                as: 'shape',
                                cond: { $in: ['$$shape', arr] }
                            }
                        },
                        marca: "$marca",
                        modelo: "$modelo",
                        fabricante: "$fabricante",
                        sensor_type: {
                            name: "$sensor_type.name",
                            type: "$sensor_type.type",
                            place: "$sensor_type.place",
                            img: "$sensor_type.img",
                            name_comun: "$sensor_type.name_comun",
                            medida: "$sensor_type.medida",
                            interfaz: "$sensor_type.interfaz"
                        }

                    }
                }


            ],
            (err, Station_types) => {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' })
                if (!Station_types) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })
                    /*SensorRecuperado.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return b.name_comun.localeCompare(a.name_comun);
                    })*/
                res.status(200).send({ Station_types })
            })
    }
```

Hope that helps.